# Looping Vector with character and random values

Tags: r, loops

How would you loop a vector with random numerical elements in a vector but at the same time wish to maintain the same characters?

I did an example below but the variables are in sequence. I would like the numbers to be randomly selected from the sequence instead.

```
x <- as.list(seq(1,10))
y <- as.list(seq(1:50))

answer <- NULL
for(n in 1:length(x)){
answer <- paste("The value of", 1:length(y) , " + ", 1:length(x) , sep=" ")
}
answer
```

Comment: Not sure what you are really asking here, but `unlist(x) + unlist(y)` may be helpful.. ?

Comment: You don't need the `for`loop. It only calculates the same thing several times. The result is the same if you only use `answer <- paste("The value of", 1:length(y) , " + ", 1:length(x) , sep=" ")`

Comment: Lists are great! Use lists when you are storing big complex objects (data frames, linear models) or when you are storing different sorts of objects (a  string in one element, a matrix in the next...). Don't use lists when what you have is a bunch of simple objects of the same type (all numbers or all characters), just use a vector (which is what you have if you delete your `as.list()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advice guys. Be sure to keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are asking for, but you might try this:

```
x <- as.list(seq(1:10))
y <- as.list(seq(1:50))
set.seed(1234) # set seed for reproducibility
x1 <- unlist(sample(x,length(x))) # shuffle the entries of x in a random fashion and store in x1
y1 <- unlist(sample(y,length(y))) # do the same for the entries of y and store in y1
answer <- paste("The value of", y1 , " + ", x1 , sep=" ") # generate result
> head(answer)
#[1] "The value of 35  +  2" "The value of 27  +  6" "The value of 14  +  5" "The value of 44  +  8" "The value of 48  +  9" "The value of 38  +  4"
```

The combinations of x1 and y1 are random (if you look carefully at the result you will see that the sequence x1 is repeating as the vector is recycled, but the order of y1 is completely random). Each value of y1 appears once, however, the pairs (x1, y1) are not the same as the pairs (x,y) in the original, ordered set. Does this correspond to your desired output?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you RHertel.